# Trying to find unique IDs with all of the values it qualifies for in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

To be quite honest I am not entirely sure how to describe what it is I am trying to accomplish? But, here it goes anyway. I have an excel sheet containing one column of IDs and a second column of values that need to be associated to the first column. The problem is that the IDs in column A contain duplicates, which is okay because one ID can qualify for multiple values. What I need is to have a third column pull back the unique id, and a fourth column pull back a semi-colon delimited list of all of the values the id qualifies for. Hopefully the attached image makes sense? For what it's worth I have tried every formula I can think of, and I really know nothing about macros, which is what I am thinking needs to be implemented.[image: Attribute Values]

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()

    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowC As Long
    lastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowC = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & lastRowC)

    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Set rngSearch = Range("A1:A" & lastRowA)

    Dim rngFind As Range

    Dim firstCell As String

    For Each cell In rng

        Set rngFind = rngSearch.Find(What:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            temp = rngFind.Offset(0, 1)
            firstCell = rngFind.Address

            Do While Not rngFind Is Nothing

                Set rngFind = rngSearch.FindNext(After:=rngFind)

                If rngFind.Address <> firstCell Then
                    temp = temp & ";" & rngFind.Offset(0, 1)
                Else
                    Set rngFind = Nothing
                End If
            Loop

        End If

        cell.Offset(0, 1) = temp
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh,first of all thanks for the quick reply. Second,I apologize, but I know NOTHING about macros, which is what I am assuming the above code is. That said, can you please tell me where I would add the code?

Comment: @Eric i have uploaded a sample file link http://sdrv.ms/Ycy5Pu . Kindly enable the macro settings and click on run button on excel file. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I apologize Santosh, but I was not able to find a way to enable the macro settings?

Comment: @Eric you may refer this link for excel 2010 http://www.troublefixers.com/enable-the-macros-in-microsoft-office-excel-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach, that has several advantages

- it builkds the list of unique sku's
- it clear old data from columns `C:D`
- it will run much faster than looping over a range

---

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rngA As Range, rng as Range
    Dim datA As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim dic As Object

    Set sh = ActiveSheet  ' can change this to your worksheet of choice
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With sh
        ' Get data from columns A:B into a variant array
        Set rngA = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        datA = rngA

        ' Create list of unique sku's and built value strings
        For i = 1 To UBound(datA)
            If dic.Exists(datA(i, 1)) Then
                dic(datA(i, 1)) = dic(datA(i, 1)) & ";" & datA(i, 2)
            Else
                dic.Add datA(i, 1), datA(i, 2)
            End If
        Next

        ' Clear exisating data from columns C:D
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        If rng.Row > 1 Then
            rng.Clear
        End If

        ' Put results into columns C:D
        .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(dic.Count + 1, 3)) = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)
        .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(dic.Count + 1, 4)) = Application.Transpose(dic.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

How to add this:

- Start the VBS editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> from excel)
- show project explorer, if its not already visible (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- add a `Module` (right click on your workbook, Insert, Module)
- open the module (dbl click)
- Add `Option Explicit` as the first line, if not already there
- copy paste this code into module

How to run it, from Excel

- activate the sheet with your data
- open macro dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)
- select `Demo` from list and run

Comment: Hi Chris, when I follow the steps above I get Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object. If I debug it the line: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") is highlighted

Comment: I am not sure how to thank the both of you for your help, but if there is something I need to do help your ratings or something please let me know. If anyone else is in this situation this is what worked for me:

Comment: Sub MG29Apr31
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dn As Range
Dim Txt As String
Dim unQ
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
For Each Dn In Rng
    If InStr(Txt, Dn) = 0 Then
        Txt = Txt & "," & Dn
    End If
Next Dn
    unQ = Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(Txt, 2), ","))
        ReDim Preserve unQ(1 To UBound(unQ, 1), 1 To 2)
Dim n As Long
For Each Dn In Rng
    For n = 1 To UBound(unQ)
        If Dn = Val(unQ(n, 1)) Then unQ(n, 2) = IIf(unQ(n, 2) = "", Dn.Offset(, 1), unQ(n, 2) & ";" & Dn.Offset(, 1))
    Next n
Next Dn
Range("C1").Resize(UBound(unQ), 2) = unQ
End Sub